# How to extract shape descriptors from 3D binary image or it's mesh representation (vertices and faces)?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, 3d, shapes

I am trying to extract shape descriptors such as Hu Moments, spherical harmonics, etc. from 3D binary images and/or their mesh representation.  I came across plenty of packages in both Matlab and Python that can be used to extract shape descriptors from 2D image.

For example there is scikit-image,

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.moments

in python and a number of factory-built and user-built functions in Matlab.

The only thing that I found for 3D image is SPHARM-MAT for Matlab
http://imaging.indyrad.iupui.edu/projects/SPHARM/SPHARM-docs/C01_Introduction.html

This toolbox calculates spherical harmonics from both 3d binary image and mesh representation of it. But it has not been updated since its release and I am struggling with lots of errors.

So, in the mean time I am looking for alternatives.

Are there any image processing packages to extract shape descriptors from 3d binary images or the mesh representation of the deformable surfaces? (preferably in Python and Matlab)

Comment: arent't hu moments defined for 2D only? Are you looking for 3D descriptors or do you want to project your 3D objects and describe single views?

Comment: Initially Hu moments were described for 2D only. But they have been extended/generalized to 3D too.

Comment: so you are searching some kind of library that has 3D hu moment computation included? If those exist, it's imho more likely that they work with meshes than with 3d images, but I can't help there, sorry. Maybe have a look at PCL (point cloud library), but that's just a guess, or some voxel processing libraries, I don't get the name atm... mostly used for medical images.

Comment: I am not specifically looking for 3D Hu moments. I am looking for any rotational invariant feature descriptors of a 3D shape. For example, 3D Zernike moments. And .. I can produce mesh representation of a 3D image, so it should not be a problem.

Comment: have a look at point cloud library: http://robotica.unileon.es/mediawiki/index.php/PCL/OpenNI_tutorial_4:_3D_object_recognition_%28descriptors%29#Table and maybe search for matlab implementations of the same descriptors